# Action when UIPopover is dismissed

Tags: ipad

Im making an app for the iPad and started making some Popovers. What I wanted to do now is:
Have a UIImageView in the Original View, that changes when the popover is opened.

```
SignalImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PopoverOn.png"];
```

That works perfectly fine. But now im looking for a place to embed the inverse code:

```
SignalImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PopoverOff.png"];
```

This should be called as soon as the PopOver is dismissed. I tried using ViewDidLoad but the view does not reload when the popover is closed because it runs in the background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a delegate for your `UIPopoverController` and implement `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly... My bad, I probably should have checked the iOs Reference Library more thoroughly :D Ill try next time!